# AttributError : 'NeuralNetwork' object has no attribute 'initialize'?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am learning python programming and machine learning for my academic project and i found  interest in number plate recognition.

By executing below code, i am getting error, which is mentioned below after the code

```
values=      
    ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Z']
keys=range(32)
data_map=dict((keys, values))

def get_ann(data_map):
feature_mat=[]    
label_mat=[]
for keys in data_map:
    path_train="/home/sagar/Project data set/ANPR/ann/%s"%data_map[keys]
    filenames=get_imlist(path_train)
    perfeature_mat=[]
    perlabel_mat=[]

    for image in filenames[0]:
        raw_image=cv2.imread(image)
        raw_image=cv2.cvtColor(raw_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        #resize the image into 5 cols(width) and 10 rows(height)
        raw_image=cv2.resize(raw_image,(5,10),                            interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        #Do a hard thresholding.
        _,th2=cv2.threshold(raw_image, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        #generate features
        horz_hist=np.sum(th2==255, axis=0)
        vert_hist=np.sum(th2==255, axis=1)
        sample=th2.flatten()

        #concatenate these features together
        feature=np.concatenate([horz_hist, vert_hist, sample])

        # append these features together along with their respective labels
        perfeature_mat.append(feature)
        perlabel_mat.append(keys)

    feature_mat.append(perfeature_mat)
    label_mat.append(perlabel_mat)

# These are the final product.
bigfeature_mat=np.vstack(feature_mat)
biglabel_mat=np.hstack(label_mat)

# As usual. We need to convert them into double type for Shogun.
bigfeature_mat=np.array(bigfeature_mat, dtype='double')
biglabel_mat=np.array(biglabel_mat, dtype='double')

#shogun works in a way in which columns are samples and rows are features.
#Hence we need to transpose the observation matrix
obs_matrix=bigfeature_mat.T

#convert the observation matrix and the labels into Shogun RealFeatures and MulticlassLabels structures resp. .
sg_features=RealFeatures(obs_matrix)
sg_labels=MulticlassLabels(biglabel_mat)

#initialize a simple ANN in Shogun with one hidden layer.
layers=DynamicObjectArray()
layers.append_element(NeuralInputLayer(65))
layers.append_element(NeuralLogisticLayer(65))
layers.append_element(NeuralSoftmaxLayer(32))
net=NeuralNetwork(layers)
net.quick_connect()
net.initialize()

net.io.set_loglevel(MSG_INFO)
net.l1_coefficient=3e-4
net.epsilon = 1e-6
net.max_num_epochs = 600

net.set_labels(sg_labels)
net.train(sg_features) 
return net
```

The errors:

```
 AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-28-30225c91fe73> in <module>()
 ----> 1 net=get_ann(data_map)

 <ipython-input-27-809f097ce563> in get_ann(data_map)
  59     net=NeuralNetwork(layers)
  60     net.quick_connect()
 ---> 61     net.initialize()
  62 
  63     net.io.set_loglevel(MSG_INFO)

 AttributeError: 'NeuralNetwork' object has no attribute 'initialize'
```

Platform used: Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7, opencv-2.4.9, iPython notebook and  shogun toolbox.

Can any one please help me in resolving this error? Thanks in advance. 
The other code samples are as follows, which have been executed before the above code.

```
from modshogun import *
def get_vstacked_data(path):
    filenames=np.array(get_imlist(path))
    #read the image
    #convert the image into grayscale.
    #change its data-type to double.
    #flatten it
    vmat=[]
    for i in range(filenames[0].shape[0]):
    temp=cv2.imread(filenames[0][i])
    temp=cv2.cvtColor(temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    temp=cv2.equalizeHist(temp)
    temp=np.array(temp, dtype='double')
    temp=temp.flatten()
    vmat.append(temp)
    vmat=np.vstack(vmat)
    return vmat
    def get_svm():
#set path for positive training images
path_train='/home/sagar/resized/'
pos_trainmat=get_vstacked_data(path_train)

#set path for negative training images
path_train='/home/sagar/rezize/'
neg_trainmat=get_vstacked_data(path_train)

#form the observation matrix
obs_matrix=np.vstack([pos_trainmat, neg_trainmat])

#shogun works in a way in which columns are samples and rows are features.
#Hence we need to transpose the observation matrix
obs_matrix=obs_matrix.T

#get the labels. Positive training images are marked with +1 and negative with -1
labels=np.ones(obs_matrix.shape[1])
labels[pos_trainmat.shape[0]:obs_matrix.shape[1]]*=-1

#convert the observation matrix and the labels into Shogun RealFeatures and BinaryLabels structures resp. .
sg_features=RealFeatures(obs_matrix)
sg_labels=BinaryLabels(labels)

#Initialise a basic LibSVM in Shogun.
width=2
#kernel=GaussianKernel(sg_features, sg_features, width)
kernel=LinearKernel(sg_features, sg_features)
C=1.0
svm=LibSVM(C, kernel, sg_labels)
_=svm.train()

_=svm.apply(sg_features)
return svm
```

ocr classification

```
def validate_ann(cnt):
rect=cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)  
box=cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) 
box=np.int0(box) 
output=False
width=rect[1][0]
height=rect[1][1]
if ((width!=0) & (height!=0)):
    if (((height/width>1.12) & (height>width)) | ((width/height>1.12) & (width>height))):
        if((height*width<1700) & (height*width>100)):
            if((max(width, height)<64) & (max(width, height)>35)):
                output=True
return output
```

Comment: Please post error messages as text, do not post them as images.

Comment: @sampada, thanks for your suggestion.  can i get solution for my question

Comment: @ sabuncu     this is the error                                                          AttributeError                           
<ipython-input-28-30225c91fe73> in <module>()
----> 1 net=get_ann(data_map)

<ipython-input-27-809f097ce563> in get_ann(data_map)
     59     net=NeuralNetwork(layers)
     60     net.quick_connect()
---> 61     net.initialize()
     62 
     63     net.io.set_loglevel(MSG_INFO)
" AttributeError: 'NeuralNetwork' object has no attribute 'initialize' "
can any one please help me regarding this
​

Comment: You need to show the code that you tried.  Don't expect others to go to the blog article and research the code.  Also, you need to edit your question and add the error you get INTO THE BODY OF THE QUESTION.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu, i apologize for my mistake and thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Sabuncu, sir i have edited my query, i have mentioned the code which i executed and error i have got, can you tell me what is wrong in the execution process.

Comment: Do you have any `import` statements at the top of your file?

Comment: @ sabuncu, in this piece of code, there is no any import statement. previous to this code, there are two code samples, one is used to train dataset based on SVM, after this code there are three more samples but it is not linked to this code and other is for OCR classification, these two codes are mentioned above

Comment: I have not been able to find the libraries you are using in your code.  I am sorry I cannot be of further help.

Comment: @Sabuncu, no problem thanks for your feedbak.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are some method deprecations issues with Shogun.

Try to replace:

```
net.initialize()
```

With:

```
net.initialize_neural_network()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
from modshogun import *' to 'from shogun import *
```

Please also change `box=cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect)`  under `ocr` classification to

```
box=cv2.boxPoints(rect)
```